# Растянуть карту по высоте и ограничить видимость yandex map api

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как можно ограничить зону просмотра карты, чтобы при дальнем зуме на карте не было видно серые поля (Для этого участка местности нет данных).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В документации нашел [restrictMapArea](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#Map__param-options.restrictMapArea), но эксперементальным путем не получилось подобрать оптимальные координаты, чтобы влезал весь мир и не оставалось этих полей.
На сайте Яндекс карт сделано это, но в исходниках не смог найти примера https://yandex.ru/maps/geo/moskva/53166393/?ll=89.423509%2C40.234010&z=2

Нужно видеть карту всего мира, чтобы она растягивалась на всю высоту блока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось подобрать координаты через сервис [openstreetmap](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html), теперь не показывает лишнего.

> restrictMapArea: [[85.23618,-178.9], [-73.87011,181] ]

```
<div id="map" style="width: auto;height: 97vh"></div>


ymaps.ready(init);
function init(){
  const myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.75416516221803, 37.62024197620109],
    zoom: 1,
    type: 'yandex#map',
    controls: ['zoomControl'],
  }, {
    suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
    restrictMapArea: [[85.23618,-178.9], [-73.87011,181] ]
  });
}
```